# What does the cloaker see?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The cloaker (page 41, Monster Manual) ability "*False Appearance*" says

> While the cloaker remains motionless without its underside exposed, it is indistinguishable from a dark leather cloak.

**My Assumption**
It seems to me that the head of the cloaker is placed where the inner face of a cloak's hood is supposed to be.

**Question**
While being worn by someone where is the cloakers point of view? Is it on the back of the head of the wearer or a little bit higher than the wearer's point-of-view?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### A cloaker has 60 feet darkvision

If False Appearance would affect the cloaker's senses, it would say so under the False Appearance or Senses entry. The Senses entry says:

> **Senses** darkvision 60 ft., passive Perception 11

Therefore, by the rules, using False Appearance does not influence the cloaker's ability to see. How you narratively explain this is up to you. You could say the cloaker just opens its eyes a tiny slit, too small to be perceptible.

You are not able to wear a cloaker as a cloak without realizing it is a monster. It is not indistinguishable from a cloak once the pale underside is exposed. If you tried to put it on, you would expose the pale underside and realize it is not a leather cloak. This is also expanded on in the lore entry for the cloaker

> When a cloaker unfurls and moves to attack, it reveals its pale underside and makes its true nature evident. Red eyes glow above rows of sharp teeth, and a long pendulous tail whips behind it.

So, it only looks like a cloak when hanging on the wall, and while it remains motionless without its underside exposed, not overall.

You can rule as a DM that the cloaker is blind while using False Appearance. The rules do not tell you to do that, but give you license to do that (DMG, p. 4)

> The D&D rules help you and the other players have a good time, but the rules aren't in charge. You're the DM, and you are in charge of the game

Cloakers are also pretty intelligent (actually [more so than the average player character](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16826-cloaker)), so you maybe could also rule that a cloaker that cooperates with a character and allows itself to be worn by a character could deceive others and look like the character wearing a cloak — as long as the character wraps him close so that the underside cannot be seen, and the cloaker does not move by itself.

If you allow that: it's not clear if a cloaker even has a hood-like section (it does not look like it from the illustration). Wearing it with the hood up if it had one would again expose the underside somewhat, so either way, there is probably no hood worn. Most likely the point-of-view would be somewhere underneath the back of the wearer's neck. This again would be up to DM ruling, as none of this is explicitly described.

Comment: You might mention that the rules assume that (at least over the course of your turn, and at any point you can act), all creatures have 360 degree vision and complete positional awareness of all non-hidden creatures in line-of-sight.  Even wearing something like a great helm does not restrict one's field of view.

Comment: @Kirt That's how we play. There is DMG p 251, "To precisely determine whether there is line of sight between two spaces, pick a corner of one space and trace an imaginary line from that corner to any part of another space. If at least one such line doesn't pass
through or touch an object or effect that blocks vision such as a stone wall, a thick curtain, or a dense cloud of fog-then there is line of sight.". Is there something like it that does not assume a grid?